# uncaught error data undefined on ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making an ajax call (JavaScript) which generates through the show info function the data I'm retrieving. My problem is as follows: On one of the arrays some data don't have it, there are not many but there is still some. So it's displaying the first items but it stops when it can't retrieve the said array and return a:

> Uncaught TypeError: info["xxxx"] is undefined.

What I'd really like is to be able to make it so it still retrieve / display the datas and says something like 'this data.[denomination][0].title is undefined or anything else'.

I tried to use the optional chaining operator '?.' but I clearly have no idea on how it works.

Here's what makes me get crazy: (it's the data["denomination"] that ruins it all)

```
request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
    if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
        const backCall=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if(backCall.count != 0){
        for(let data of backCall.datas){
            showInfo(data.title, data["author"][0].name, data["denomination"][0].title, data["denomination"][0].id);
        }
    }else if(backCall.count === 0){
        noResult();
    }
}
});
```

(just a little edit to be precise. I searched before hand and even looked up to the advised subjects from Stack when I was writing this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if both properties exist in the object and then call your showinfo function, it should not fail

```
for (let data of backCall.datas) {
  if (data["author"] && data["denomination"]) {
    showInfo(data.title, data["author"][0].name, data["denomination"][0].title, data["denomination"][0].id);
  }
}
```